# titanium maps api, Map doesnt load

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, titanium

it loads the gui, i can press my location, i basicly see myself on the map aswell, als a blue dot. I also see annotations but the map itself remains gray. I do have internet connection. I use the following code :
Map.js

```
var MapModule = require('ti.map');


var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
var mountainView = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude:37.390749,
    longitude:-122.081651,
    title:"Appcelerator Headquarters",
    subtitle:'Mountain View, CA',
    pincolor:MapModule.ANNOTATION_RED
});

var eentweedrie = MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude:51.32811396764682,
    longitude:3.850465540405268,
    title:"school",
    subtitle:'terneuzen',
    pincolor:MapModule.ANNOTATION_RED
});



var mapview = MapModule.createView({
    mapType: MapModule.NORMAL_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993,
            latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[mountainView, eentweedrie]
});
win.add(mapview);
win.open();
```

tiapp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <id>com.Innovisionsolutions.com</id>
    <name>mbo app</name>
    <version>5.64.15</version>
    <publisher>IVS</publisher>
    <url>http://</url>
    <description>not specified</description>
    <copyright>2014 by IVS</copyright>
    <icon>logo.png</icon>
    <persistent-wifi>false</persistent-wifi>
    <prerendered-icon>false</prerendered-icon>
    <statusbar-style>default</statusbar-style>
    <statusbar-hidden>true</statusbar-hidden>
    <fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>d39ece47-4841-4499-a992-b8788db55848</guid>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">system</property>
    <iphone>
        <orientations device="iphone">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        </orientations>
        <orientations device="ipad">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
        </orientations>
    </iphone>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <manifest>
            <!-- Allows the API to download data from Google Map servers -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <!-- Allows the API to cache data -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <!-- Use GPS for device location -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
            <!-- Use Wi-Fi or mobile connection for device location -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
            <!-- Allows the API to access Google web-based services -->
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
            <!-- Specify OpenGL ES 2.0 as a requirement -->
            <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="com.innovisionsolutions.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
            <permission android:name="com.innovisionsolutions.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
            <application>
                <!-- Replace "PASTE YOUR GOOGLE MAPS API KEY HERE" with the Google API key you obtained -->
                <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAxgb4M6UEszyMstdTvak_AmQDRo0xItNA"/>
            </application>
        </manifest>
    </android>
    <mobileweb>
        <precache/>
        <splash>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
        </splash>
        <theme>default</theme>
    </mobileweb>
    <modules>
        <module platform="android">ti.map</module>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="iphone">true</target>
        <target device="ipad">false</target>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="blackberry">false</target>
        <target device="mobileweb">true</target>
        <target device="tizen">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>3.1.2.GA</sdk-version>
    <property name="ti.deploytype">test</property>
</ti:app>
```

I've checked the key and its the same as my api account.

Can someone help me out and get this map loaded?

Thanks in advance!!! :D

Comment: I think your API key is missing something.check it again

Comment: @Dragon Same key. 

Key for Android apps (with certificates)
API key: 
AIzaSyAxgb4M6UEszyMstdTvak_AmQDRo0xItNA

Comment: Mostly, it may be the problem of API key. Did you create the key using SHA1 key?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to change the following lines in the Android manifest section of your tiapp.xml file, replacing the **com.innovisionsolutions.com** with your **actual** application's ID (package name) which is **com.Innovisionsolutions.com**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.Innovisionsolutions.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="com.Innovisionsolutions.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

After that, you have to create a new Google Maps API Android key following this pattern:

> [cert_fingerprint];[package_name] AKA [your keystore's SHA1
>   fingerprint];[your application's correct case sensitive id]

for example:

> 45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;**com.Innovisionsolutions.com**

and finally, replace the Android API key created, here:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="PASTE YOUR GOOGLE MAPS API KEY HERE"/>
```